# Writing 2 strings on the same line in C

Tags: c, cstring

So I want to make the hello.c program write both the first name and the last name on one line so in this form but when I run my program in this current form it gives me  the error "expected â)â before string constant" I think I have the rest of the code down because I have removed that line and ran it and it works. So I just want to ask how to get 2 strings that I have already pointed to to go on the same line.

This is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  char firstname[20];
  char lastname[20];
  printf("What is your firstname?");
  scanf("%s", firstname);
  printf("What is your lastname?");
  scanf("%s", lastname);
  printf("Hello %s\n", firstname "%s", lastname);
  printf("Welcome to CMPUT 201!");
  }
```

Answer (score 7):

You want

```
printf("Hello %s %s\n", firstname, lastname);
```

instead of

```
printf("Hello %s\n", firstname "%s", lastname);
```

Comment: (Also, you probably want something to protect against buffer overflows when reading in names; what if someone enters in 21 characters for one of them?)

Comment: I used char (firstname) because my prof said we needed to use a name less than 20 but I would use fgets or increase the amount of memory allocated for the strings in the char. Would that work?

Comment: Yeah, I'd advocate something like `fgets` that reads in no more than a set limit if you want to extend it. Though if you're guaranteed that everything is less than 20, you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    char first_name[20] = " ", last_name[20] = " ", full_name[40] = " ";
    printf("What is your firstname?\n");
    scanf("%s", first_name);
    printf("What is your lastname?\n");
    scanf("%s", last_name);
    sprintf(full_name,"%s %s",first_name, last_name);
    printf("name is %s\n",full_name);
    return 0;
}
```

I have shown the same using sprintf.

1) also in your program you are not returning anything, if dont want to return anything make it as void function. When you write int function, always make it an habbit to return the integer.

2) Also when you write the printf function always make it habit to add \n(new line) so the output looks good

happy coding.

Comment: "if dont want to return anything make it as void function." NO! `void main()` is a strict NO!

Comment: @HAL can you please explain the reason. For best of my knowledge when i don't want to return anything void must be used. Please feel free to correct me.

Comment: According to C99 standard.

Comment: If you are planning on just printing `full_name`, **don't** write it to a string first and then print out. Print it out directly.

Comment: @Shahbaz ya just wrote this to show the possibilities that can be possible,